# Electrum: Transaction Error with Restored Wallet

Tags: transactions, electrum, cli

I am trying to import my bitcoin privatekey to my electrum wallet and use that wallet to create transactions.

I restored the wallet using the command `electrum restore <private key>`

The restore was good and I was able to get my balance to show up correctly via `electrum getbalance`, everything looked fine until I try to create a transaction, and it gave me this error

`electrum.util.NoDynamicFeeEstimates: Dynamic fee estimates not available`

Does anyone know why this happened?

I am using the latest electrum.

Edit: The error only shows up with a restored wallet, I can send transactions with my sweep wallet without any problems

Answer (score 1):

you need to set fee manually. goto preferences and check edit fee manually.